Dividing Overlapping Periods in SQL
I have this table in SQL (called "df"):
         v1         v2   v3         v4 name
 2015-06-23 2024-06-09 2013 2015-03-31  red
 2015-06-23 2024-06-09 2014 2015-03-31  red
 2015-06-23 2024-06-09 2018 2019-03-18  red
 2015-06-23 2024-06-09 2020 2021-02-21  red
 2015-06-23 2024-06-09 2023 2024-03-15  red
 2015-06-23 2024-06-09 2013 2015-03-31 blue
 2015-06-23 2024-06-09 2014 2015-03-31 blue
 2015-06-23 2024-06-09 2018 2019-03-18 blue


CREATE TABLE df (
    v1 DATE,
    v2 DATE,
    v3 INT,
    v4 DATE,
    name VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO df (v1, v2, v3, v4, name) VALUES
('2015-06-23', '2024-06-09', 2013, '2015-03-31', 'red'),
('2015-06-23', '2024-06-09', 2014, '2015-03-31', 'red'),
('2015-06-23', '2024-06-09', 2018, '2019-03-18', 'red'),
('2015-06-23', '2024-06-09', 2020, '2021-02-21', 'red'),
('2015-06-23', '2024-06-09', 2023, '2024-03-15', 'red'),
('2015-06-23', '2024-06-09', 2013, '2015-03-31', 'blue'),
('2015-06-23', '2024-06-09', 2014, '2015-03-31', 'blue'),
('2015-06-23', '2024-06-09', 2018, '2019-03-18', 'blue');

For each color, I am trying to perform the following calculation:

Step 1: How many years are there between : [max(V2)  - min(V1)] + 1?
Step 2: What values of V3 are between : Year[max(V2) - 1] to Year[min(V1) - 1]
Step 3: How many values of V3 are in the answer of Step 2?
Step 4: Division : Step 3/ Step 1

As an example, in the case of 'red':

Step 1: 10 Years : 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024
Step 2: Years: 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023
Step 3: Number of Years = 4 (2014, 2018,2020, 2023)
Step 4: 4/10 = 0.4

I tried to write the SQL code for this problem using a separate CTE for each step:
WITH step_1 AS (
    SELECT
        name,
        YEAR(MAX(v2)) - YEAR(MIN(v1)) + 1 AS YearRange
    FROM df
    GROUP BY name
),
step_2_part1 AS (
    SELECT
        name,
        YEAR(MAX(v2)) - 1 AS MaxYear,
        YEAR(MIN(v1)) - 1 AS MinYear
    FROM df
    GROUP BY name
),
step_2_part2 AS (
    SELECT
        d.name,
        d.v3
    FROM df d
    JOIN step_2_part1 s2p1 ON d.name = s2p1.name
    WHERE d.v3 BETWEEN s2p1.MinYear AND s2p1.MaxYear
),
step_3 AS (
    SELECT
        name,
        COUNT(v3) AS V3Count
    FROM step_2_part2
    GROUP BY name
),
step_4 AS (
    SELECT
        s1.name,
        CASE
            WHEN s1.YearRange = 0 THEN 'Error: denominator is 0'
            ELSE CAST(s3.V3Count AS FLOAT) / s1.YearRange
        END AS Result
    FROM step_1 s1
    JOIN step_3 s3 ON s1.name = s3.name
)
SELECT * FROM step_4;

My Question: I am not sure if I am doing Step 3 correctly. I am not sure if I need to add an extra CTE and use a sub-select/subquery along with the IN statement to correctly identify this range of years.
Can someone please help me do this correctly?
Thanks!

Hi - Does your SQL return the correct result? If so then it’s correct, otherwise it isn’t. If it’s not returning the correct result then please update your question with the result it’s returning and what you want it to return

try:
WITH step_1 AS (
    SELECT
        name,
        YEAR(MAX(v2)) - YEAR(MIN(v1)) + 1 AS YearRange
    FROM df
    GROUP BY name
),
step_2_part1 AS (
    SELECT
        name,
        YEAR(MAX(v2)) - 1 AS MaxYear,
        YEAR(MIN(v1)) - 1 AS MinYear
    FROM df
    GROUP BY name
),
step_2_part2 AS (
    SELECT
        d.name,
        d.v3
    FROM df d
    JOIN step_2_part1 s2p1 ON d.name = s2p1.name
    WHERE d.v3 BETWEEN s2p1.MinYear AND s2p1.MaxYear
),
step_3 AS (
    SELECT
        name,
        COUNT(v3) AS V3Count
    FROM step_2_part2
    GROUP BY name
),
step_4 AS (
    SELECT
        s1.name,
        CASE
            WHEN s1.YearRange = 0 THEN 'Error: denominator is 0'
            ELSE CAST(s3.V3Count AS FLOAT) / s1.YearRange
        END AS Result
    FROM step_1 s1
    JOIN step_3 s3 ON s1.name = s3.name
)
SELECT * FROM step_4;

